# How to extract the option fields in TCP header for a pcap file using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, tcp, pcap

How to extract the option fields in TCP header using C/C++ in case of an offline pcap file. I tried including the option field within header structure, but it doesn't give a consistent result when I compare the result with Wireshark. It seems arbitrary bytes are going missing when accessed through TCP header structure. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to read the file directly, use `pcap_open_offline` or `pcap_fopen_offline` from `libpcap`. This will read the save file in and allow you to supply filters. The pseudocode goes like this (you will need to add error handling):

```
char *fname = "/path/to/my/file";
const u_char *packet;
pcap_t *handle;

handle = pcap_open_offline (fname, errbuf);

while (packet = pcap_next(handle,&header))
{
    char *data = (char *) packet;
    ...
}

pcap_close (handle);
```

If by any chance you are already using `libpcap`, you'll have to post the code. Remember that to find the IP headers reliably you will need to check the ethernet type (`ETHER_TYPE_IP` vs `ETHER_TYPE_8021Q`), then find the TCP header (the length of the IP header can vary), and only then will you get a pointer to the TCP header.